# I have to filter images without javascript or divs :/

Tags: html, css

For a project for university we have to make a product page where the customers can filter the products(images) based on a certain trait(Brand in my case). I have tried to do this with the help of buttons and checkboxes, but without javascript or divs it has been quite the challenge to make it work. I have put the images in a table as this is easier to give a structured look.Thanks in advance for taking a look at my code!

```css
tr {
  position: relative;
}

.ImgProd {
  border: solid 3px dimgrey;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.filteredtable tbody tr,
.tablefilter {
  display: none;
}

#class1.tablefilter:checked~table tbody tr.class1,
#class2.tablefilter:checked~table tbody tr.class2,
#class3.tablefilter:checked~table tbody tr.class3 {
  display: table-row;
}

.tablefilter+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}

.tablefilter:checked+label {
  background-color: #111;
}


/*hiermee zorgen we ervoor dat de image zoomt wanneer de gebruiker erover hovert*/

.ImgProd:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.tableProducten {
  position: relative;
  left: 6%
}
```

```html
<h1>Onze producten</h1>
<!-- we gebruiken buttons als fitler element tussen de verschillende merken van auto's -->
<input type="checkbox" class="tablefilter" name="class1" id="class1" checked />
<label for="class1">Mercedes</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tablefilter" name="class2" id="class2" checked />
<label for="class2">BMW</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="tablefilter" name="class3" id="class3" checked />
<label for="class3">Opel</label>

<table class="tableProducten">
  <tr class="class1">
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/AMG_GT4.jpg" alt="AMG GT4" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/BenzSla.jpg" alt="BenzSla" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/Cla.jpg" alt="Cla" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/DEX.jpg" alt="DEX" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/Eklas.jpg" alt="Eklas" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/EQC.jpg" alt="EQC" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/Mercedes/SUV.jpg" alt="SUV" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class2">
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/AC.jpg" alt="bmw AC" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/IX3.jpg" alt="IX3" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/M2.jpg" alt="M2" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/M5.jpg" alt="M5" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/M6.jpg" alt="M6" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/X1.jpg" alt="X1" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/BMW/Z4.jpg" alt="Z4" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="class3">
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/Adam.jpg" alt="ADAM" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/Astra.jpg" alt="Astra" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/ComboL1.jpg" alt="ComboL1" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/Corsa.jpg" alt="Corsa" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/CorsaX.jpg" alt="CorsaX" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="../resources/OPEL/MokkaX.jpg" alt="MokkaX" class="ImgProd">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's some weird requirements, especially about the divs.  I have no idea how you could dynamically filter content without javascript.

Comment: The approach using `#class1.tablefilter:checked ~ table tbody tr.class1` looks good and valid to me. Maybe your browser doesn't automatically add the tbody which you use in your CSS selector but not in your HTML code?

Comment: Are you using a backend at all?  The only way I can see this happening is if you use a form to submit the filter selections and only return the data that matched the filter in the backend

Comment: I just realized that you don't hide the rows of the table because you use different class names on the table in CSS and HTML. `<table class="tableProducten">` vs. `.filteredtable tbody tr`

Comment: an old dabblet of mine(6years old)  using pure CSS ,its  input and label filtering imag in figure via classnames , all inserted into a form*( which can allow you to submit your choices/filtering )*  I was testing HTML5 and transition http://dabblet.com/gist/4262212 (design is not my thing .. )

Comment: here another example to hide/show columns and or table rows https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HBjDn . hope this helps you to sort out classnames to filter whatever you want next your checked inputs Here is the pen version of the dabblet, easier to play with https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk

Comment: that's so stupid of me, thanks for all the help guys. It means a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your CSS (you don't use the same class name in your selector that you have given your table in HTML)

```
.tableProducten tbody tr,
.tablefilter{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: That was the stupidest thing I've done in a long time, thanks for helping me! It means so much